# confusion about array and object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want format like that

```
"attechent":[{
        "name":xyz,
        field: [ 
            { title: 'a' }, 
            { title: 'b' } 
              ]
       }
    ]
```

code->>

```
var field=[]
var obj1={"title":"a"}
var obj2={"title":"b"}
field.push(obj1)
field.push(obj2)
console.log(field)

var outerfiled={}
outerfiled.field=field
out.name="xyz"
console.log(outerfiled)

var list=[outerfiled]
console.log(list)
```

problem is like my code is working   according to desire output format but after
output is `[ { field: [ [Object], [Object] ], name: 'xyz' } ]`

Comment: That is just what `console.log` does. Do this instead: `console.log(JSON.stringify(list))`

Comment: Looks correct. Maybe use `console.log( JSON.stringify( list, null, 2  ) )` to have something looking more similar to your requested format.

Comment: I'm not sure wether you think you have to build this structure like that; step by step, property by property. Do you know, that you can do the following? `var list = [
 { 
  name: 'xyz', 
  field: [ 
   { title: 'a' }, 
   { title: 'b' } 
  ]
 }
]` *(the linebreaks are not shown in a SO comment, but you can add even them)*

Comment: @thomas this will generate on the fly. Object in filed can by n, and n will decide on the run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output which you're seeing is the standart Node output when printing and Object. It shows that it has an Object, but does not print it out in detail.

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will allow you to format your object as required. It takes three arguments - the object to format, an optional replacer function, and an optional indent level. Note that the order of properties is not guaranteed.

In your case, you do not need to use the replacer function, so pass null as the second argument. The required indent level is 4 spaces, so you can pass the number 4 as the third argument.

```js
var field=[]
var obj1={"title":"a"}
var obj2={"title":"b"}
field.push(obj1)
field.push(obj2)

var outerfiled={}
outerfiled.field=field
outerfiled.name="xyz"

var list=[outerfiled]

var result = {attechent: list}
// Extra args for JSON.stringify:
// no replacer function required - pass null, indent level of 4 spaces required
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
```

Comment: this ans is giving correct format, but what is null and 4, how you choose 4. Ans should be generalize.

Comment: @AakashKag Most computer systems have "documentation" which you can consult, and that is more efficient than asking on SO. In this case, google for "JSON.stringify" to find out what the parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

You need the right variable for the name.

```
outerfiled.name = "xyz";
// ^^^^^^^
```

and later an assignment to the result, like

```
var result = { attechent: list };
```

```js
var field = [];
var obj1 = { title: "a" };
var obj2 = { title: "b" };
field.push(obj1);
field.push(obj2);

var outerfiled = {};
outerfiled.field = field;
outerfiled.name = "xyz";

var list = [outerfiled];
var result = { attechent: list };
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` doesn't print the whole object. You can use util.inspect() if you want to print the whole object. Here is the code

```
var utl = require("util");

var field=[]
var obj1={"title":"a"}
var obj2={"title":"b"}
field.push(obj1)
field.push(obj2)
console.log(field)

var outerfiled={}
outerfiled.field=field
outerfiled.name="xyz"
console.log(outerfiled)

var list=[outerfiled]
console.log(utl.inspect(list, false, null))
```

Comment: this is output coming using util  { attechment: '[ { field: [ { title: \'a\' }, { title: \'b\' } ], name: \'xyz\' } ]' }

Comment: I agree object problem will solve by json as well as util. Now my output is like [ { field: [ { title: 'a' }, { title: 'b' } ], name: 'xyz' } ]. but for attachment  var outerobj={"attechment":list}

console.log(outerobj)